# Disable message / call notifications for one specific contact

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, notifications

One of my contacts is annoying me with text messages. I could block them, but then I'd never be able to see the messages they send and I want to have the ability to do that.

So instead the idea I had was to turn off text message notification sounds / badges / etc for just this one specific contact.

Is this possible? It seems like I can turn off notifications for people not in my contacts, but really I just want to turn them off for this one specific person.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leave them in contacts rather than remove, but set all their ringtones/messages sounds to a silent ringtone.

There's one [here](http://richardkmiller.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/silence_ringtone.php)
linked from this page - [How can I get a silent ringtone on my iPhone?](http://www.iphonefaq.org/archives/971156) on the iPhoneFAQ site.

You'll still get the notifications, but no sounds.

Comment: but i'll still see the text messages on my home screen even though it won't play a sound, yeah? is there any way to prevent these from appearing on my home screen?

Comment: Only by removing them from Contacts & setting the notifications pref as you suggested in your question.

Comment: argh! and there's no way to access the text messages that a blocked caller sends me? (really i want "the same thing as blocking the person but i can see the messages they've sent me if i want to)

Comment: You can't really block & not block at the same time ;-)

Comment: This is about two years after the question...but would http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/189972/no-sms-notifications-for-one-contact be a better answer now?

Answer (score 7):

Leave them under your contacts and then click the "do not disturb" when you click on the info of their text message.

Comment: This has been renamed to “Hide Alerts” in more recent versions of iOS.