# No SMS notifications for one contact

Tags: iphone, notifications, sms

I have a weird problem. For this one contact I don't get any sound or vibration notifications when a SMS arrives.

What I have tried:

- Change Text Tone
- Change Vibration
- Delete contact and create new with same mobile number
- Rebooted iPhone

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have accidentally muted the SMS conversation.
To change this go to the SMS messages for that contact and click `Details` (top right) and make sure that `Do Not Disturb` isn't selected.