# iPhone: Blocking calls by ignoring

Tags: iphone, call

I want to block certain phone calls with my iPhone. However, the block list in iPhone actively blocks users and the caller known that he's being blocked.

However, sometimes you do NOT want the blocked user to know that he is blocked. So sometimes I just want to ignore callers (i.e., no incoming call notifications etc)

Is there any way and/or app to achieve this?

Comment: It's worth noting that parts of call blocking features appear to be carrier dependent and may not behave the same way from carrier to carrier.

Comment: How about just a silent ringtone? See http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/158401/85275

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there is no such possibility in regular iOS.

I did find [this app/tweak (iblacklist)](http://www.iblacklist.com.br/) that does what you want, although that's on Jailbroken devices only.

Comment: As I'm unable to comment (due to not having the rep) on @IconDaemon 's answer ill do it here instead.
While people generally won't be told that they are blocked, it's quite easy to deduct if you are blocked simply by calling multiple times and seeing if it only rings exactly one time every time. [Here is a link on how one could figure that stuff out](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iphone/how-tell-if-someone-has-blocked-your-phone-number-on-their-iphone-3638817/)

Answer (score 1):

The information in this [Apple Support Document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201229) states:

*When you block a phone number or contact, they can still call you or send you a message, but you won't get a notification. Also, the contact won't get a notification that the call or message was blocked.*

I'm inferring from the wording ***...the contact won't get a notification...*** that *only* a phone call/message from a number in your Contacts will not see a 'blocked call' response.

One solution is to add these phone numbers into your Contacts. Callers shouldn't be able to see that they've been blocked. I have not tested this, so YMMV.